# `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)

Tags: ruby, merb

I am new to the ruby on merb, using ruby 1.8.7 version. while run the app it showing like this

```
`default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound) 
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:242:in `default_gemfile'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:188:in `root'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:98:in `bundle_path'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:395:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:89:in `configure'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:150:in `definition'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:115:in `setup'
    from /usr/bin/merb:10
```

when i am trying to install  ' rvm rubygems 1.4.2 ' it shows followed message like

```
Installed rubygems 2.0.14 is newer then 1.4.2, skipping installation, use --force to force installation'
```

This is to request you to provide the solution at the earliest possible. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Ruby you shouldn't use 1.8.7. Its no longer supporter and you will run into problems beyond the one you are having right now. Upgrade to Ruby 2.1.1:

```
rvm get stable
rvm install 2.1.1
```

Then locate your project and install your gems by running:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue trying to get TextMate 2 working with the Cucumber bundle from 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-tmbundle

I'm using rvm integration with **TM_RUBY** set to my **.rvm/bin/rvm_auto_ruby**, but the cucumber not be resolved.  I ended up hard coding **BUNDLE_GEMFILE** and **GEM_HOME** into the 'Run Feature' and 'Run Single Scenario' commands:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = ENV['TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY'] + '/Gemfile'
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/Users/my/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@monaco-mongoid3'
```

Anyways, hope that helps someone else.